# No Access-Control-Allow-Origin header, but it is

Tags: ajax, angularjs, cross-domain

I'm using AngularJS in the front-end, PHP in the back-end, and Yeoman during developing (with the angular-generator).

I'm getting the following error when trying to make an AJAX request through the $http service:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load 
https://someweb.com/some/path/app/scripts/php/getSomething.php?term=someParticularValue. 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
Origin 'http://localhost:9000' is therefore not allowed access.
```

However, the headers are properly set in the PHP side, and actually I don't have any cross domain problem at all when trying to type the URL directly in the browser (I get the JSON I am expecting, and when look at the headers via the Chrome DevTools everything looks right).

The AJAX call in Angular looks like this:

```
$http.get(phpBaseUrl + 'getSomething.php', {
    params: { term: someValue }
})
.then(function (res) {
    // Do something with res.data ...
});
```

I also tried the same code with Firefox, since I read that there can be some problems in Chrome. I'm using Linux (Ubuntu 14.04).

I'm a bit desperate, because for each single character I change, I have to upload the files to the server if I want to check if the new thing is working, which actually takes me about between 1 and 2 minutes. I'm not being productive at all!

Any ideas about the root of the problem?

Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

To use CORS within Angular, we need to tell Angular that we’re using CORS. We use the
`.config()` method on our Angular app module to set two options.

1. We need to tell Angular to use the XDomain and
2. We must remove the X-Requested-With header from all of our requests

   ```
   angular.module('myApp')
    .config(function($httpProvider) {
       $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
       delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers
               .common['X-Requested-With'];
   });
   ```

Comment: I can't test it now, but tomorrow I will do. However, I don't think is this kind of issue because 1) I already tried to delete that header (not setting the useXDomain to true) and 2) it was working on a Mac computer with the same PHP and nothing configured like this (in an old and messy version of the same project, which I cannot find differences with).

Comment: Thanks Aditya, I was facing the same problem...

I tried the solution provided by you..and it works perfectly.

Comment: @DanielM Check the Url for the php page as to whether it is able to return you the json. That can be the only issue

Comment: I'm not sure about what you say (sometimes my English is not good enough, and this doesn't help). The PHP URL is correct, since when I get the error I can see the URL where I'm getting the error; then I can open it on a new tab, and the JSON is returned properly, what is very estrange, actually.

Answer (score 0):

You should not need anything on angular side, it is the php side that should config CORS. ps browser does not have cors issue always

Comment: As I said, I already include the proper headers... And in fact it works without problems when I try to access the URL from the browser.

Comment: I think neither browser nor curl has CORS issue.

Answer (score 0):

Good news, I managed to solve it! I come back just to share what was the problem, if this could be helpful for anybody else.

The thing is that I am working inside of quite a big network and I don't understand all his points. The problem was: the X-Domain problem seemed to be in the PHP files I was called (that was the browser said -- in fact this files sent the proper headers already, and I hadn't to modify them). But this was not true; the real X-Domain problem was produced by another file (probably not PHP, I don't know) which implements a necessary login system. I was being redirected to this "hidden" file under the hood each time I try to make a request to the first one. The "hidden" file, which I don't control, hasn't the proper headers to allow X-Domain calls, of course, so that's why my calls didn't succeed.

So, the only thing I needed to do was tell the suitable person to change the network properly, to avoid this problem caused by the redirect. Indeed I think that he removed the redirect.

Sorry for keep you thinking in vain, and thank you for your tries.